# Unusual type error in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a function that takes in list of True or False (representing a binary number) and it is suppose to pad the array with False
However I am getting a very weird type mismatch error.

When I do

```
let pad x y = 
    [False;False]
;;
```

It returns that array fine (thought not the correct one) and when I do

```
let pad x y = 
    x
;;
```

It returns the original array fine
However when I try to concatenate the two together like so

```
let pad x y = 
    x::[False;False]
;;
```

I get an error saying one is of type formula and one is of type formula list

It also works fine if I do

```
let pad x y = 
    False::x
;;
```

But throws a type mismatch error when I do

```
let pad x y = 
    x::False
;;
```

Sorry if this is convoluted but its all the information I have managed to gather on the error

Comment: A list is given as the parameter sorry I must of typed it wrong. I have changed it for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 2):

`::` is not the concatenation operator, `@` is.

`::` takes an element and prepends it to a list. So the left operand is an element and only the right operand is a list. When you do `x :: [True; False]`, both operands are lists of the same type, so the left operand isn't an element that can be put into the the right operand. When you do `x :: False`, the right operand isn't a list. `False :: x` is the only one that works because it's the only one where the right operand is a list and the left operand is an element that fits into that list.

To concatenate two lists use `@` like this:

```
x @ [False; False]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `::` operator works on lists. In OCaml lists and arrays are two different things.

Specifically, the `::` operator takes (on the left) a value, and (on the right) a list of the same type of value. It returns a new list with the value added at the front of the list. This is a pretty fast operation (constant time).

You can also concatenate two lists with `@`. This takes time proportional to the length of the list at the left. So it can be slow.